# Include a javascript for composite component only once in a page despite of composite components themselves used multiple times

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

How do I include a JavaScript code only once for multiple usages of a  composite component on a page?

Initially I had put I put the JS code inside the `cc:implementation` tags but that lead to the script being included each time with the components. I want to avoid this condition and include the JavaScript only once even if component has been used multiple times on a page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Include the static part of that JS code as a standalone JS file by [`<h:outputScript>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) with `target="head"`. It'll be rendered into `<h:head>` just once.

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputScript name="js/myCompositeHelper.js" target="head" />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: Has something changed here? I used <h:outputScript target="head"> to include Leaflet and GoogleMutant for Leaflet inside a component.

The web browser consoles says "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."