# Include a JS script not in the header but in the footer of the page?

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets, composite-component

I'm doing a JSF Composite, but I m having a hard time with including my JS scripts inside. I'm tying this:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputScript name="js/myCompositeHelper.js" />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

Here are the questions:

1. For some reason, I cannot put a path inside of the name attribute, I get an error.  What am I doing wrong?
2. I know of target='head', but for websites, it's better to put the JS in the footer, so how can I do that?

Thanks for any help.
PS: I've seen this, but [Include a javascript for composite component only once in a page despite of composite components themselves used multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392337/include-a-javascript-for-composite-component-only-once-in-a-page-despite-of-comp)

Comment: I have no idea why you initially tagged `[jsp]`, but it makes absolutely no sense, so I removed it. You're using its successor `[facelets]`. Composites are impossible in JSP. Please be careful what you're tagging and be aware about what you're really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *1. For some reason, I cannot put a path inside of the name attribute, I get an error. What am I doing wrong?*

I have no idea what your problem is as you didn't describe the error in detail (the error message is usually the whole answer at its own). In any way, the markup and the `name` looks fine so far, assuming that it's indeed placed in `/resources` folder of public webcontent.

---

> *2. I know of target='head', but for websites, it's better to put the JS in the footer, so how can I do that?*

Use `target="body"`. It'll end up in end of body.

Comment: ha, thanks for that.  Question 1 you were spot on, I put the JS in the wrong folder. Question 2: Works like a charm!  Thanks again.